# LINQ Normalizing data

Tags: c#, sql, linq, union, normalize

I am using an OMS that stores up to three line items per record in the database.

Below is an example of an order containing five line items.

```
Order Header
Order Detail
   Prod 1
   Prod 2
   Prod 3
Order Detail
   Prod 4
   Prod 5
```

One order header record and two detail records.

My goal is have a one to one relation for details records(i.e., one detail record per line item). In the past, I used an `UNION ALL` SQL statement to extract the data. Is there a better approach to this problem using LINQ?

Below is my first attempt at using LINQ. Any feedback, suggestions or recommendations would greatly be appreciated. For what I have read, an `UNION` statement can tax the process?

```
var orderdetail =
    (from o in context.ORDERSUBHEADs
        select new { 
            edpNo = o.EDPNOS_001, price = o.EXTPRICES_001, 
            qty = o.ITEMQTYS_001 }
    ).Union(from o in context.ORDERSUBHEADs
        select new { edpNo = o.EDPNOS_002, price = o.EXTPRICES_002, 
            qty = o.ITEMQTYS_002 }
    ).Union(from o in context.ORDERSUBHEADs
        select new { edpNo = o.EDPNOS_003, price = o.EXTPRICES_003, 
            qty = o.ITEMQTYS_003 });
```

Comment: Are the `E..._00n` names fixed in that form? And what happens if there are less than three? `null` values?

Comment: Yes, the tables columns are fixed with _00n. The schema was migrated from an HPe3000 IMAGE database that supported data types as arrays. The item level detail was stored in arrays. If only one line item is present, the item ID for the other two values will be zero. The same applies to the price and quantity. There is no chance for a null value. The columns have default values of zero or spaces. The reasoning behind all of this was to save space back in the day. The designers took the most common number of line items on an order and created the order detail schema.

Thanks,
Brennan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id build a simple sub-class

```
class Record 
{
    public object SubHeading { get; set; }
    public int EdpNo { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Then you just loop over it all

```
var orders = context.ORDERSUBHEADs.Select(o => 
   new Record[] {
      new Record { SubHeading = o, EdpNo = o.EDPNOS_001, Price = o.EXTPRICES_001, Quantity = o.ITEMQTYS_001 },
      new Record { SubHeading = o, EdpNo = o.EDPNOS_002, Price = o.EXTPRICES_002, Quantity = o.ITEMQTYS_002 },
      new Record { SubHeading = o, EdpNo = o.EDPNOS_003, Price = o.EXTPRICES_003, Quantity = o.ITEMQTYS_003 }
   }
);

IEnumerable allOrders = IEnumerable.Empty;
foreach(Record[] r in orders)
    allOrders = allOrders.Concat(r);

IEnumerable allRecords = allOrders.Cast<Record>();
```

But frankly your `o` structure sucks, you should build the list of items as an `IEnumerable` or `IList` or something, not `#Parameters * #Rows`.

Comment: Are you referring to the database schema?